# C# Start and Stop Thread inside SAME button click event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am using C#,.Net4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to get this behaviour from my windows form application when the user click on a button:

1. A GUI LED starts to blink
2. A long rung operation starts
3. When the operation at point 2 ends the LED stops blinking

   ```
   private void Btn_WebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Thread_Blink = new Thread(() => { LED_Blink(LED.WS); });
       Thread_Blink.Start();

       // Do something that takes time.. Let's imulate with a sleep
       Thread.Sleep(2000);

       Thread_Blink.Abort();
   }
   ```

I also tried using 3 different events and/or timers..

```
private void Btn_WebService_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Timer_Blink.Enabled = true;
}

private void Btn_WebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something that takes time.. Let's imulate with a sleep
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

private void Btn_WebService_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Timer_Blink.Enabled = false;
}
```

The result is always the same: The LED starts to blink only AT THE END of the long running operation (`Thread.Sleep(2000);`) and suddenly STOPS so that you can't see anything. Why does this happen and how can I get the desired behaviour?

I add further infos. I tried to use BackgroundWorked and implemented the wanted behavour in this way:

```
private void Btn_WebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BlinkWorker.RunWorkerAsync(LED.WS);
        LedOn(LED.WS);

        TestWebService();   // This method takes about 2 seconds to answer..

        LedOff(LED.WS);
        BlinkWorker.CancelAsync();
    }
```

While the TestWebService() is running I get the LED off(LedOn(LED.WS);). When the TestWebService()has finished the LED comes on. 
The BlinkWorker still does not work if started and cancelled inside the Click event.

FYI: If I make a button that starts the blinking and another button that stops it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you're tying up the UI thread inside that `Thread.Sleep`. The UI thread is special - it's the only one that can make changes to the UI - so whilst it's busy sleeping, it's not able to service any attempts from your `BackgroundWorker` or `LED_Blink` timer callback to change the UI state.

So, you need to not tie up the UI thread. You need to put the `Thread.Sleep` code (or it's actual real equivalent) into the `BackgroundWorker`s `DoWork` handler, or use other means to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Common approaches today would be to make use of `async`/`await` if the real work you're trying to do already offers an asynchronous alternative (e.g. `await Task.Delay(2000);` would be the equivalent of your current `Thread.Sleep(2000);`). Unfortunately, using `async` and `await` would require you to move to a later version of .NET/Visual Studio - but you ought to be considering that anyway. 2010 is quite dated (and also, IMO, probably the worst one to stop on - it was notoriously slow), and .NET 4.0 (as opposed to .NET 4.5.2 or later) is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you take a look at the BackgroundWorker class and the ReportProgress method.